# What prevents the mass production of fetishes?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, werewolf-the-forsaken

From the setting it seems fetishes should be fairly rare. However I'm wondering what is preventing a character with three key rituals: Call Jaffling, Bind Spirit, and Fetish Rite from making a a lot of fetishes. Basically making fetishes commonplace within the pack.

Bind Spirit takes some time to set up. 20 successes on extended int + occult each roll representing 1 minute of work. And finally a harmony vs resistance once the spirit shows.

Call Jaggling requires 50 successes on a extended harmony roll, again each roll representing 2 minute.

Fetish Rite require 15 + 10 / lvl successes on an extended harmony roll again requiring one minute per roll. And an expenditure of 1 essence per level.

This means that making a level 3 fetish require a total of 20+50+45 successes and 3 essence. Even a moderate estimate of one success per roll would allow a character to make a level 3 fetish in about 2 hours.

Just to reiterate the question:
**What is preventing a character from making a lot of fetishes, and making them commonplace within the pack or werewolf society?**

Comment: Just to be sure. Are you specifically looking for a cannon in-universe explanation or a mecanical one to prevent it happening in your game? (Assuming you're que GM) Or whichever works.

Comment: I'm open for any method of handeling it from: the RAW will prevent this because you have overlooked this rule. To: in my campaign we dealt with it this way with this result. Even references to systems outside of 1st editions with decent ways of handeling it.

Answer (score 5):

**Fetishes by description in the setting of W:TF are actually fairly common** -- they are by no means ubiquitous but we can extrapolate from what little text is directly on the topic of these pieces of equipment that they are not exactly legendary, one-of-a-kind magic items. At five dots -- maybe four? -- perhaps but certainly not at one and two (which have fairly minor, utility effects). Also, **expect Talens to be adorned all about the place** where Uratha have set-up shop or live: "Moon's Allure"[1] (pg. 205) would be exceedingly useful in a bar which werewolves frequent!

**Werewolves almost always will attune themselves to a Fetish** in order to use it. This means they must find time in the day to wear it for at least one hour. They must also take the time to coax the spirit (more powerful ones are harder and scarier to) into the vessel to enable supernatural effects. Technically, they do not *have* to attune themselves but then a major benefit of a fetish is that it adapts in form and size to the werewolf making it incredibly useful when shapeshfiting.

**Why make one when you can take one?** As Cunning is a Renown score, it would be more worth it to trick, charm or outright steal a Fetish from another Uratha. And losing one (especially a strong one) is a sure hit to an Uratha's Glory score. Is it really worth the risk?

**Using Essence as an activation shortcut gets expensive for younger Uratha** -- this is somewhat mitigated by elder Uratha having bucketloads of it. But then, they'll very likely have other on-going expenses to worry about. Having a font of Essence available to a werewolf is not exactly easy -- the usual suspect, Loci, require constant TLC for industrial application to even be feasible.

**Powerful spirits absorbed into fetishes attract attention from the spirit world.** A Werewolf that is known for abusing spirits in this way may find their continued efforts to construct more Fetishes are made difficult (the Rite of Contrition is mentioned as an acceptable means of apology). Other, more conservative Uratha may take issue with trying to turn what is supposed to be a sacred, personal ritual into an industrial exercise and it could be argued doing so could constitute Harmony loss at high levels. **This is dangerous as Harmony is required for a werewolf to create a fetish in the first place** (Harmony - Spirit level; pg. 204)

**They must know the Fetish Rite (et al.) in the first place to create them.** Many werewolves are far more likely to learn Rituals or Gifts that actually support them day-to-day and at-will rather than an item that's utility is based on having it with them at the exact moment they need it. It will get to the point where the cost of planning involved to do so significantly outweighs the benefits -- it's a bit ridiculous (but there's always one who just HAS to have their Bear's Growl fetish made from a gross, old bear's tounge...) **And, of course, Fetish Rite, Bind and Call Jaggling are expensive Rites being 4-dots and two 3-dots, respectively.**

[1]

> MOON’S ALLURE
>
> Made from crushed flower petals, this powder mitigates the effect that Lunacy has on humans. When the powder is sprinkled on
> a human subject, her Willpower is considered to be three dots higher
> than normal when exposed to the maddening sight of a werewolf’s
> supernatural powers. A cat-spirit empowers this talen. The effect
> lasts for the remainder of the scene.
>
> Action: Instant

Comment: Do you have a reference for the "attune" part? I can't say that I have seen it in Forsaken, but remember it from Apocalypse.

Comment: @Marius "A character may attune himself to a fetish by wearing it next to his skin for one hour and succeeding on a Harmony roll. " pg. 204, WTF.